# Custom Web part in sharepoint 2013 to display videos from local computer

Tags: html, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

can we make custom web part to show videos from physical location?
E.g if we upload videos to C:\videos folder and show it in sharepoint site?
I mean where my web front server is installed there in c drive if i place all my videos than is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Your browser default security scheme doesn't allows to read local files.

Also, consider other SharePoint users: should they access files onto *your* machine?

**EDIT**
Accessing *web server* local files is possible, but they must be kept inside your virtual directory, or you'll need to write custom code (an .ASHX file, maybe) to read an arbitrary file and redirect its contents to your video player.

Comment: I mean where my web front server is installed there in c drive if i place all my videos than is it possible?

Comment: Can u pls give me some url or example for custom code.